# how to set authorize attribute by source application/URL

Tags: c#, .net-core, authorization, authorize

I have a .NET core web API server that I am communicating with (post/get) from two applications.
The first is an angular website and the second one is a WPF app.
I want the angular website to get response only with JWT Token Bearer and the WPF to get the responses without any need for Authorization.
should I create two controllers? one without Authorize attribute for WPF and one with Authorize attribute for angular? or there is another way to do it with custom Authorize attribute that check if request come from angular or from WPF?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not require the WPF client to authenticate, this means that you need to open the methods for anonymous access.

For this to work, you do not have to create two controllers, but can use the authorization attributes `Authorize` and [`AllowAnonymous`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to decide which methods require an authenticated user (Angular) and an unauthenticated one (WPF).

Please note that if you use the `AllowAnonymous` attribute on a method in a controller with an `Authorize` attribute, `AllowAnonymous` overrides `Authorize` so that you can access the method without and authentication.

Comment: But it's about the same HTTP methods that should be once enabled without a token for WPF and once disabled without a token for angular

Comment: Why do the Angular requests need a token? How do you discern between a request from Angular and one from WPF? Is the API publicly available or do the WPF clients use an internal one in the network?

Comment: Because this is what the Boss wants :). Both on the same outside network no one use internal

Comment: How should the WPF app (or its user) proove that it is your WPF app and not just some script kiddie playing with curl? Is it ok for an anonymous user to access the API?